# Vuforia target appears black on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm trying vuforia and unity, with the purpose of building for android. I have a cylinder prefab recognising a food can I have, however when I load this on my phone the cylinder target appears over my can as a black cylinder.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Make sure you use supported materials, Vuforia can be quite tricky. Refer to this link: https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Compiling-a-Simple-Unity-Project